# Creating an untraditional form input for record edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, salesforce

On the platform I'm building my react app on, they have these form input fields call "Lookup Fields". Essentially what they are fields that the user cannot type into, but they click a button, search for the value by modal, then click on a result to set the fields value. Here are screenshots of what I'm describing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

These inputs give me no problems when I'm creating a record. Problems arise when I try to create an edit form for the record.

Here is the code for how the edit form is rendered.

First checking if `editMode` is `active`. If so then it goes through an array of the records and only displays the record with matching id.

```
  renderEventForm() {
    if(this.props.editMode.active) {
      const editRecordId = this.props.editMode.eventId;
      let events = this.props.events;
      for(var i in events){
          if(events[i].Id === editRecordId) {
              return <Update
                      exitEditMode={this.props.exitEditMode}
                      updateEvent={this.props.updateEvent}
                      event={events[i]}
                     />
          }
      };
    } else {
     return(
       <Create
         Owner={this.props.Owner}
         What={this.props.What}
         StartDateTime={this.props.StartDateTime}
         EndDateTime={this.props.EndDateTime}
         Who={this.props.Who}

         createEvent={this.props.createEvent}
         getWhat={this.props.getWhat}
         toggleModalContactSearch={this.toggleModalContactSearch}
       />
     )
   }
  }
```

Once the edit form component is rendered, the correct values display, but I'm puzzled on how to update the "Contact" field value. The reason for this is I'm passing the record into the component as a prop. Look specifically in the section label "Contact".

```
import React from 'react';

class Update extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.exitEditMode = this.exitEditMode.bind(this);
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  exitEditMode() {
    this.props.exitEditMode();
  }

  handleChange(e, event) {
    const updatedEvent = {
      ...event,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
    console.log(e.target.value, event);
    this.props.updateEvent(event, updatedEvent );
  }

  toggleModal() {
    this.props.toggleModalContactSearch();
  }

  render() {
    let event = this.props.event;
    return (
      <form className="slds-form">
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Assigned To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input name="OwnerName" type="text" className="slds-input" value={event.Owner ? event.Owner.Name : ''} disabled/>
            <input name="OwnerId" type="hidden" className="slds-input"  value={event.Owner ? event.Owner.Id : ''} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Related To</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input name="WhatName" type="text" className="slds-input"  value={event.What ? event.What.Name : ''} disabled/>
            <input name="WhatId" type="hidden" className="slds-input"  value={event.What ? event.What.Id : ''} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Subject</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input name="Subject" type="text" className="slds-input" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e,event)} value={event.Subject ? event.Subject : ''} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Location</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input name="Location" type="text" className="slds-input" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e,event)} value={event.Location ? event.Location : ''} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Description</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <textarea ref={(input) => this.Description = input} type="textarea" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e,event)} className="slds-textarea" value={event.Description ? event.Description : ''} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event Start</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input name="StartDateTime" type="text" className="slds-input" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e,event)} value={event.StartDateTime ? event.StartDateTime : ''} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label">Event End</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input name="EndDateTime" type="text" className="slds-input" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e,event)} value={event.EndDateTime ? event.EndDateTime : ''} disabled/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-form-element">
          <label className="slds-form-element__label" htmlFor="input4">Contact</label>
          <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <section className="slds-clearfix">
              <input name="WhoName" className="slds-input" style={{maxWidth: '92%'}}  value={event.Who ? event.Who.Name : ''} disabled/>
              <input name="WhoId" type="hidden"  value={event.Who ? event.Who.Id : ''} disabled/>
              <button  type="button" className="slds-button slds-button--icon-border slds-float--right" aria-live="assertive" style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlinkHref={searchIcon}></use>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="slds-p-top--x-small">
          <button type="button" onClick={this.exitEditMode} className="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Exit</button>
{/*          <button type="submit" className="slds-button slds-button--brand">Update</button>
          <button type="button" className="slds-button slds-button--destructive">Delete</button> */}
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Update;
```

The value for "Contact" is set by prop. At the root level if my app, there is a `Who` value in state that is used in creating a record for the contact value, so I can pass it down as a prop to the edit form, but the gist is, is it possible to juggle between two props for a value on an input? From what I understand about React, you shouldn't use `defaultValue` and `value` together, but I thought about putting the `prop.event` value in the `defaultValue` field, and `prop.selectedContact` in the `value` field.

If I'm going about this the wrong way, I'm open to another implementation, thanks.